# Font scaling Chrome not working

Tags: css, font-size

Given this CSS

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
    color:#333
}

.post_text p {
    font-size: 1.2em
}
```

why doesn't text in `.post_text p` scale on Chrome when I click Ctrl-+?

It does behave correctly on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this buried in my css

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none
```

which obviously will cause the behavior I described in OP.

Answer (score 1):

It **does** scale correctly, which I've checked using Chrome 21.0.1145.0 dev-m using this jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9yuPN/

I'm guessing that you may have some other conflicting style rules or a problem with your browser? Try viewing that jsFiddle above and see if the example scales when you use Ctrl + '+' and Ctrl + '-'. If this doesn't work for you, it's not the code that is the problem and it's likely your browser/OS or something else, and if the jsFiddle DOES work for you, the problem is somewhere else in your code.

As you have written it, it should scale correctly in Chrome (and does for me).